# How to use window.onload function just once

Tags: javascript, iframe

Can someone tell me how to load an iframe (just once) on the first page of my website then never to appear again after I closed it?.

I tried using window.onload but my problem is every time I clicked some button that requires to go back to index the iframe still appearing.

here is my code for reference:

```
<div id="promotion" ahref="https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.656868614427098.1073742013.368809253233037&type=3">
    <div>
    <span id='close' title="close video" onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'>x</span>
    <iframe style="background: (opacity 0.8)"id="promotional_video"  src=" https://www.youtube.com/embed/rF7cnRn1B68?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered session state (if available), or cookies?

Answer (score 0):

One way to prevent the function to run again would be to set a **cookie** and check it before inserting the frame into the document, where the frame should be.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(document.cookie.toString().indexOf("showedFrame=1")!=-1) {
        document.cookie="showedFrame=1";
        document.write("<div ...... </div>");
    }
</script>
```